# logstash http-poller input force ipv6 usage?

Tags: logstash, ipv6, logstash-configuration

I would like to force the http_poller to use ipv6 first prior to ipv4.

The host running logstash is dual stacked and the target host also.
The issue lies in the ACL on the target host only accepting requests from the IPv6 addresses on the vhost configured.

curl works as it is default ipv6 first if dual stacked and ipv6 addresses are returned by dns (but also ipv4).

When in touch with the supplier of the endpoint it seemed that we are going over ipv4 when using the http_poller input from logstash iso ipv6, I see no options in the plugin to force ipv6 and the supplier is not going to change its dns, nor allowing our ipv4 address.

I know that I could create a workaround with having an exec input that handles the request, but I consider this only as a last resort.

Someone who has an idea on how to solve it?

Update: I already looked into the info of manticore http client, but did not find a solution there (thanks Badger for reminding me to share the fact that I already looked into this)

Comment: A quick check of the [manticore](https://github.com/cheald/manticore) documentation does not show an option to do this.

Comment: In case you do not understand why I linked to that, the http_poller filter is a wrapper around the logstash http mixin, which is a wrapper around the cheald Manticore http client.

Comment: I knew this and looked in it as well, maybe someone else knew a workaround :)